# Finding intersection of spans in 2 inconsistent systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given 2 sets of matrices:

$$
S1 = \begin{pmatrix} 
1&0&1\\
0&2&1\\
2&1&0\\
1&1&2
\end{pmatrix}\
$$

$$
S3 = \begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0&2\\
1&0&2&2\\
0&2&2&1\\
2&2&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where each column in each matrix corresponds to a vector.

In a previous part, where I had to find which vector in S3 belonged in span(S1), I came to a conclusion that none of S3 lay in S1 via Gauss Jordan Elimination due to inconsistency in all vectors.

Now in another part, I am told to find the intersection between span(S1) and span(S3). From what I recall from class, finding the intersection between the two spans involves solving them in a linear system, in which case, I have already concluded that it is inconsistent. In such a case, is there still any intersection at all? If there is, how do I actually find it when the system is inconsistent? Am I missing any concept?

Answer (score 1):

First, there's an obvious element in the intersection: the zero vector, because it's in the span of **any** set of vectors.

Let me give you a concrete example to show what you're not understanding, but still give you the chance to solve the problem. Let's look in 3-space. Let
$$
v_1 = \pmatrix{1\\1\\0}, v_2 = \pmatrix{-1\\1\\0}\\
w_1 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\1}, v_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\-1}.
$$
It's pretty clear that neither $w_1$ nor $w_2$ is in the span of ${v_1, v_2}, because all vectors in that span have 3rd coordinate zero.

On the other hand, the vector $s = \pmatrix{0\\2\\0}$ is certainly in the span of the $v$-vectors (it's $v_1 + v_2$) and the $w$-vectors (it's $w_1 + w_2$).

So even though neither $w_1$ nor $w_2$ is in the span of the $v$s, the span of the $v$s and the span of the $w$s intersect. (The intersection is all vectors of the form $\pmatrix{0\\t\\0}$, where $t \in \Bbb R$).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I can catch your explanation clearly now. But would you mind providing a hint on how you obtained $$\begin{pmatrix}0\\t\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ from the given vectors? Like, what mathematical procedure should I use?

Comment: I deliberately omitted that so that you could have the experience of working it out. I know that means that I haven't answered the second of your questions, so you're certainly welcome to not accept my answer.